# SUDO_ASKPASS prompt is opening on remote machine

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I am trying to rsync a directory from a remote machine to my laptop. The directory on the remote machine is not owned by the ssh user, hence I am trying to use `sudo` as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137992)

Both machines are running macOS and have both `ssh-askpass` and `XQuartz` installed. X11Forwarding is working correctly, which I tested by running `xeyes` on the remote machine via SSH. The following command opened the window on my local machine.

```
ssh -X remotehost /opt/X11/bin/xeyes
```

But when I run `ssh-askpass` on the remote machine, the prompt is opening on the remote machine, instead of forwarding it to the local machine.

```
ssh -X remotehost 'export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/local/bin/ssh-askpass; env; sudo -A ls'
```

Why isn't the `ssh-askpass` prompt forwarded to my local machine?

#### Update

On Local Machine

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.pHs2JQL4YE/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

On Remote Machine

```
$ env | fgrep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=<remote machine hostname>:10.0

$ sudo env | fgrep DISPLAY
Password:
DISPLAY=<remote machine hostname>:10.0
```

Comment: What is the value of the DISPLAY environment variable on the remote system? And what is the value of DISPLAY for commands run via sudo?

Comment: @Kenster I have added the details to the question.